# Misinterpretation of fields containing " when importing text file with tab delimiter

Tags: excel, vba, delimiter, sap-erp

To nip it right in the bud, I'm aware that opening these files through Excel and using the Import Wizard will fix this issue, however, I have already written many macros that I would prefer not to rewrite if possible.

When I export a file from SAP system in text format and `.xls` extension I can then open that file as I normally would. The Import Wizard is not triggered this way so it seems to be automatically assuming I want a quotation <s>delimiter</s> text qualifier (`"`) when I open the file.

I am running into issues since some of the items in the dataset have this quotation (`"`) which triggers the <s>delimiter</s> text qualifier and results in truncated, concatenated, and altogether messy data.

It's not feasible for me to go and change all of the code I've previously written to account for this mistake. What I would prefer is if there is an obscure Excel setting or workaround that will automatically make my <s>delimiter</s> text qualifier set to `none` on file open to avoid these issues.

When I import through the Wizard with `none` I have no issues with the dataset. It's just when I open through File Explorer (or with VBA code) that it skips the Wizard and automatically assigns a `"` <s>delimiter</s> text qualifier.

TLDR: I want my default Excel <s>delimiter</s> text qualifier set to `none` instead of `"` so I can open the text files with `.xls` extension from SAP system without data integrity issues.

- I should also note that I'm using the Tab delimiter for importing, it's just the <s>delimiter</s> text qualifier that needs to change.

Please see the examples below:

1. [image: File Type]
2. [image: Concatenated Data]
3. [image: Import Screen 1]
4. [image: Import Screen 2]
5. [image: Import Screen 3]
6. [image: SAP Text Qualifier]
7. [image: Notepad Snippet]
8. [image: Notepad Snippet 2]

Thank you.

Comment: An actual xls file has no "delimiter" so it's unclear what you're asking here...  What does "triggers the delimiter" mean?  Some examples would help.

Comment: @TimWilliams Please see the updated question above. I realize I was using "delimiter" where I meant to say "text qualifier" so I apologize for the reasonable confusion. Please also see the added photos for additional context.

Comment: From your screenshots it seems that your "Excel" file is really a plain text file with an xls extension?  So basically you need to treat it like a txt file.  Would be helpful to show a screenshot of the file opened in Notepad or some other text editor.

Comment: @TimWilliams Notepad snippet added.

Comment: Not seeing any quotes there?  Basically though it seems like you will need to bite the bullet and update your code to open the file using the text import wizard.

Comment: If a cell contains a line break then Excel surrounds that cell content with quotes when saving it in text format. If such a cell also contains a quote (e.g. 3/4" pipe) then Excel misinterpretes the inch symbol. A quote in a single-line cell seems not to cause any problem. The solution would be to double the inch symbol (3/4"" pipe).

Comment: @Stringeater - that's true but the imported file wasn't saved from Excel but from SAP (and we don't have an example to view how it looks with quotes)

Comment: Yes, I know. That's why I haven't declared it an an answer. I have come accross this quote problem many times. And either it was possible to change the export procedure or I had to pre-process the text file before opening it.

Comment: I've added a new photo to the bottom which shows the particular line of data in notepad. When this is opened in Excel without the Import Wizard it absorbs the next line in the table (see picture 2) and results in data errors.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Based on your discussion it seems like there isn't an Excel setting that will change my default text qualifier? As in it will remain ( " ) until manually changed.

Comment: I don't believe that you can change the way Excel understands quotes. So replace all quotes with another character that is not used in your data. Open the file in Excel and search and replace them back. If you already use VBA, this should be possible.

Comment: If you don't want to change your existing VBA code, then I guess you don't want to output the SAP file to a computer-comprehensible format, so the solution would be to append code before the import to update the file, just doubling the quotes as Stringeater proposed.

Comment: Not sure if it would be of any use, but a quick web search turned up this on MS website which may give some direction toward a solution
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytable.textfiletextqualifier

Comment: @GlennG thanks for sharing, I'm curious if I can run the code to change the text qualifier on workbook open and maybe that will fix the issues as far as the macros are concerned.